# EditText with "time" type not showing colon in Samsung devices

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy

I am creating an EditText programmatically, and setting its type to time:

`editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME or InputType.TYPE_DATETIME_VARIATION_TIME)`

This works in most devices, but I tested on a Samsung Galaxy A51 and A70, and both don't show the colon key (:)

[image]

I tried forcing characters with this, but it doesn't work either:
`editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789:"))`

So I'm not sure what to try to get my ":"! Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at using [MaskedEditText](https://github.com/VicMikhailau/MaskedEditText). Once you have added the library to your **build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.vicmikhailau:MaskedEditText:3.1.1'
}
```

you would simply do:

```
<com.vicmikhailau.maskededittext.MaskedEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:mask="##:##" />
```

Notice the `app:mask="##:##"` the `#` means it allows any digit and the colon would be the time separator you want. So this would allow something like 11:30 etc.

Comment: I wouldn't want to use a library for this, but I'll give it a try if I don't have any other alternative!

Comment: I don't have any alternative and this is usually why libraries are preferred over re inventing the wheel. Hopefully the library caters for the devices you mentioned as the code has been used by many more developers and should be a bit more battle tested. Unless you are writing a library for edittext masks then of course you wouldn't want to use a library